# Shell Sort Comparisons and Exchange tally

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, big-o, shellsort

I am having difficulty understanding whether or not my code is producing the correct number of exchanges(swaps) and comparisons. I get the same number for all three cases, which isn't like insertion sort. From my understanding, shell sort is an improved insertion, that performs insertion sort on gap sorted sets of numbers which makes me question whether or not these values are correct.

I have tried counting them in other places, but I believe I have them in the correct places. The only difference in values I get is when I change the gap which obviously would change the efficiency of the algorithm, but is this the only thing that changes efficiency? Or are my values incorrect?

```
int Sort(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length; 
        int exchanges = 0, comparisons = 0;

        // Start with a big gap, then reduce the gap 
        for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap = gap*3 + 1) 
        { 
            //gapped insertion sort 
            for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) 
            { 
                // add a[i] to the elements that have been gap 
                // sorted save a[i] in temp and make a hole at 
                // position i 
                exchanges++;
                int temp = arr[i]; 

                // shift earlier gap-sorted elements up until 
                // location for a[i] is found 
                int j; 
                for (j = i; j >= gap && arr[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) 
                    arr[j] = arr[j - gap]; 
                comparisons++;
                // put temp correct location 
                arr[j] = temp; 
                exchanges++;
            } 
        }
    }
```

I expected to a get a different result for the random set of values. I understand that the gap sequence partially sorts it,But I get values of  Exchanges(Swaps) - 10 & Comparisons - 5
on ascending, descending, and random values from 1-10. Which makes me hesitant to believe my values are correct. Does shell sort make insertion sort input insensitive? Any help/input is appreciated.

Comment: `gap = gap*3 + 1` doesn't reduce the gap, it increases it.

Comment: you are correct, thank you